# Zimbra several DNS names

Tags: zimbra

We have Zimbra 8.0.3 OS edition server. Our server has several A-entries in DNS-server. Let's suppose they are aaa.mydomain.com, bbb.mydomain.com and ccc.mydomain.com. Could anybody say what I should do to redirect users to page 404 when they use bbb.mydomain.com, ccc.mydomain.com and server IP-address but give them access to mail web-client if they use aaa.mydomain.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to tell I was using Jetty.

Comment: Do you really want a 404 or to redirect them to the right location using a 302 redirect?  Also is jetty out in front or is apache in the mix somewhere?  You will need to pick where you want to handle the redirects or 404.

Comment: I don't really know if jetty is behind apache or not in zimbra. I haven't much experience with web servers.
And yes, I want 404 page to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved this problem. You should add following lines into jetty.xml.in in directive < New id="zimbra" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" >...<  /New> :

```
   <Set name="virtualHosts">
       <Array type="java.lang.String">
         <Item>aaa.mydomain.com</Item>
       </Array>
   </Set>
```

Thanks everyone =)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^bbb.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .*  - [R=404]
```

You could also try a general forbidden error, like this:

```
  order allow,deny
  deny from bbb.mydomain.com
  allow from all
```

Comment: Sorry! I didn't tell that I was using Jetty =)

Comment: as far as I know zimbra use Jetty behind Apache .

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems they are independent in Zimbra.